# asp.net MVC 4 web application Server Error in '/' Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /PhoneBook/Create

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18056

When I access Create view it gives this error what is the problem?? please help

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(PhoneBookmodel phmodel)
        {
            try
            {
                _PhoneBookList.Add(phmodel);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

Comment: You have this view created ?

Comment: Do you have a folder Phonebook with the view Create in it?

Comment: I create it but doesntwork

Comment: Do you have Index view in Phonebook folder?

Comment: Do you only have the httppost create nethod? You should have two, one decorated wirh the httppost attribute as shown above, and one without.

Comment: If your `Add` fails you will return a view `Create`. If you do not have one that accepts `GET` it will say that it couldn't find a view.

Comment: Are you sure that you're making a POST request, and not the standard Http GET?

Comment: Just post screenshot of your error and your existing Controller class code.

Answer (score 0):

The reason probably is that you do not have a controller method with HttpGet Attribute. i.e. You have just one Create Action, which will be called for posting data on form submit. In order to load form with controls, you possibly need a Action method with no "HttpPost" attribute specified, which defaults to "HttpGet", once you have it it should work.

Example:
Add the below to your controller. And it should work.

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
           return View();
    }
```

Comment: nah that's not why its happening.

Comment: Aniket I believe if you only have a action method with Post attribute then it would throw 404. You can verify this in IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have created a View and your action Index is exist(return View). Also, check your virtual path in your project by right click on your project choose properties and fix this with "/". You can check your Controller too to make sure  "/PhoneBook/Create" your PhoneBook controller and Create function both of those are exist.